# @media screen of css is not working in Visual Studio 2015

Tags: css, asp.net

This is the simplest code I made in VS 2015 but it does not run and show error.

`@media` shows that does not exist in current context.

If there is a replacement syntax for this please post it.

```
 @{
 Layout = null;
 }


<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head> 
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">

  <style>
 .body{
 background:red;
 }
@media screen and (max-width: 400px) {
  .body {
    background:blue;
  }

  </style>
</head>
<body class="body">
hi
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

You left off the closing brace to your @media query.

```
@media screen and (max-width: 400px) {
  .body {
    background:blue;
  }
^
//////
```